# Cumulative distinct count with Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Using Spark 1.6.2.

Here the data:

```
day | visitorID
-------------
1   | A
1   | B
2   | A
2   | C
3   | A
4   | A
```

I want to count how many distinct visitors by day + cumul with the day before (I dont know the exact term for that, sorry).

This should give:

```
day | visitors
--------------
 1  | 2 (A+B)
 2  | 3 (A+B+C)
 3  | 3 
 4  | 3
```

- Tried self-join but really too slow
- I am sure windowed function is what I am looking for but didnt manage to find it :/

Comment: SQL Server is NOT Spark SQL.

Comment: are you looking for a solution in spark or sql-server?

Comment: oups you are right, only Spark SQL, didnt pay attention to the auto-complete sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do:

```
select day, max(visitors) as visitors
from (select day,
             count(distinct visitorId) over (order by day) as visitors
      from t
     ) d
group by day;
```

Actually, I think a better approach is to record a visitor only on the first day s/he appears:

```
select startday, sum(count(*)) over (order by startday) as visitors
from (select visitorId, min(day) as startday
      from t
      group by visitorId
     ) t
group by startday
order by startday;
```

Comment: Running 1st query give error: ``expression 'day' is neither present in the group by, nor is it an aggregate function.`` (under spark 1.6.2)

Comment: The first one didn't work for me either but the second code works well.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL, you could do this.

```
select t1.day,sum(max(t.cnt)) over(order by t1.day) as visitors
from tbl t1
left join (select minday,count(*) as cnt 
           from (select visitorID,min(day) as minday 
                 from tbl 
                 group by visitorID
                ) t 
           group by minday
          ) t 
on t1.day=t.minday
group by t1.day
```

- Get the first day a visitorID appears using `min`.
- Count the rows per such minday found above.
- Left join this to your original table and get the cumulative sum.

Another approach would be

```
select t1.day,sum(count(t.visitorid)) over(order by t1.day) as cnt 
from tbl t1
left join (select visitorID,min(day) as minday 
           from tbl 
           group by visitorID
          ) t 
on t1.day=t.minday and t.visitorid=t1.visitorid
group by t1.day
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it's

```
select
    day,
    count(*),
    (
    select count(*) from your_table b
    where a.day >= b.day
    ) cumulative
from your_table as a
group by a.day
order by 1
```

Comment: Spark 1.6.2 do not allow sub query like this :/